# Run headless chrome in Docker suddely crashes

Tags: google-chrome, 19.04, chromium, docker

We run some test in a headless chromium. As everything else, we run everything inside of Docker. Now, for a couple of days, chromium suddenly crashes on my machine (Ubuntu 19.04):

Here a minimal Dockerfile to demonstrate:

```
FROM debian

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends chromium
CMD chromium --headless --verbose --no-sandbox --screenshot https://www.chromestatus.com
```

Run `sudo docker build . -t headless-chrome-crash; sudo docker run headless-chrome-crash`

As this passes on the Mac of my colleague and Circle CI, too, the only choices were Docker, the OS and the performance of the machine. And with AWS, I was able to narrow it down to Ubuntu 19.04, **as it passes on 18.04!** It also passes when I run it directly on my machine without docker, and it was passing on my machine with Docker for a long time.

The full error is pretty long, ([see here](https://gist.github.com/iGEL/b95028cf2cecf0844307f6228993bf55)), but here is the first part:

```
[0918/134957.717636:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(170)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[0918/134957.723472:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1188)] The GPU process has crashed 1 time(s)
[0918/134957.824829:FATAL:sandbox_linux.cc(382)] Check failed: !HasOpenDirectories(). InitializeSandbox() called after unexpected directories have been opened. This breaks the security of the setuid sandbox.
#0 0x55d058895449 <unknown>
#1 0x55d0587e3d36 <unknown>
#2 0x55d0587fbd14 <unknown>
#3 0x55d059a053d4 <unknown>
....
```

On other machines, it creates the `screenshot.png` and it looks like this:

```
[0918/120635.809655:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(49)] MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed attachments: 0/1
[0918/120635.809580:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(49)] MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed attachments: 0/1
[0918/120635.809768:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(126)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuChannelMsg_CreateCommandBuffer.
[0918/120636.611712:INFO:headless_shell.cc(572)] Written to file screenshot.png.
[0918/120636.621106:ERROR:browser_process_sub_thread.cc(203)] Waited 5 ms for network service
```

The Docker version:

```
Docker version 19.03.2, build 6a30dfc
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure, this is a bug. As it's passing on other machines even with the same Docker version, I don't think that something inside the containers changed, so it's probably a bug in Ubuntu. But how to figure out who's the culprit?

Comment: I can confirm this issue on my machine (Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS with Kernel 5.0.0-29-generic).

I am running chrome with `--disable-gpu` but the main issue seems to be the same:

`[0919/140130.868900:FATAL:sandbox_linux.cc(382)] Check failed: !HasOpenDirectories(). InitializeSandbox() called after unexpected directories have been opened. This breaks the security of the setuid sandbox.`

Docker version 18.09.7, build 2d0083d

Identical image works on my Mac (Docker desktop 2.1.0.3) without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading kernel to 4.18.0-25-generic solves the issue.
Seems to be an incompatibility between Docker and Kernel 5.0.0.

Comment: Any ideas about how to get this working without downgrading?

Comment: This was indeed the problem for us, we were seeing this on a CI runner that was running kernel 5.0.0 (the others were still on 4.xx). Andreas or @EllisPercival, if you find an upstream issue for this, please post the link here so we can help others. I googled briefly but couldn't find anything obvious.